# TabControl size and locations within

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I create a TabControl with a TabPage in it. I want to have everything displayed (at least until the user resizes at run time) so I set the size of the TabControl to the ClientRectangle of the enclosing window, the size of the TabPage to the ClientRectangle of the TabControl.

This does not work. If I set the AutoScroll true for the TabPage scroll bars appear and I can then scroll to see the whole area.

I put a button at the ClientRectangle.Height - button.Height and it is in the area that is cut off.

My understanding of the ClientRectangle is that it is the area that is displayed and is a window into the DisplayRectangle, which is the area I can draw into. So, If I keep the stuff I want to see in the ClientRectangle it should be visible. Obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Of course you didn't set the size of a TabPage. That's docked inside its container, The Location of your Button depends on *when* you set its vertical position. If that happens while the TabPage is scrolled, then the Button will be placed in that relative position, determined by the current position of the DisplayRectangle (which may have negative coordinates, while the ClientRectangle location is fixed). The initial Visible property of the Button also counts: if it's not visible, then it may not have a handle; in this case, the Layout Engine cannot work on it until it creates a Handle.

Comment: I don't understand the "you didn't set the size of a TabPage."  In my code I have tabPage.Size =. Doesn't that set the size of the TabPage?

Comment: Also, when I set Autoscroll to false the button is off the bottom of the displayed window. I get the height of the ClientRectangle and subtract the height of the button to get the location.  The button has the default value for visible and, if I turn on autoscroll, I can scroll down and see it. Also, if I move the location of the button up, by say 50, when I create it I can see it.

Comment: 1. Yes, you *can  set* the Size of a TabPage. It doesn't do anything. Try in the Designer. 2. If you set the `Button.Location` to e.g., `= new Point(0, [TabPage].ClientSize.Height - [Button].Height)` at run-time and it goes outside the ClientRectangle, there's the  chance that A) You have a High-Dpi screen and you're not designing at 100% scale B. Your app is not DpiAware. C. Your TabControl undergoes multiple *transformations* in Size/Layout and when you set the Location, the ClientSize is larger. D) Something else your code is doing but you didn't mention.

Comment: 1 It does something.  At a minimum he value . Bottom returns the value I used for the height of the TabPage that I set in .Size = new Size(100 150).  OK, I just discovered that I can place a control far beyond what I set as the Size of the TabPage.

Comment: Now that I understand a bit more what is going on it looks like my idea of how to do what I want is wrong. Is there some way to in the designer have a window with a menuStrip, when I click on a menu item I want to create a TabControl that fills the window, create a TabPage and put a button at the bottom. I think I have it all working except finding the bottom of the TabPage that is visible without scrolling.

Comment: I created a test app that removes everything except the basics.  I do have a high DPI monitor, but I designed without scaling. The app is probably not DPI aware. When I run it I just click the menu item to pop the TabControl. I am unclear about the button going outside the ClientRectangle. In the constructor for the TabPage I create and set the location of the button. I do not think anything happens to the UI between when I create the stuff and it is displayed. I start the app and click the menu. nothing gets resized.

Comment: I just ran it again and resized the window before creating the TabControl. It looks like the TabControl is built to fill the existing window. When I get the ClientRectangle it looks like the value I get matches what I dragged the window size to. The problem still exists. A button placed at the bottom of the ClientRectangle - the height of the button is cut off no matter what size the window is.